# 5x5 checker board controlled by keyboard with different events at boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have this project am working on which is to traverse through 5x5 checker board with different events occurring at different boxes(positions) in the board (e.g if the person is at [2,0] an event to reduce the grid to only 2x2 size occurs or perhaps the box at [4,0] changes color)

much appreciate the help.

```js
(function() {
    // refined add event cross browser
    function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
        if (typeof elem === "string") {
            elem = document.getElementById(elem);
        }

        // avoid memory overhead of new anonymous functions for every event handler that's installed
        // by using local functions
        function listenHandler(e) {
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            if (ret === false) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return(ret);
        }

        function attachHandler() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            // and make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
            var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);
            if (ret === false) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
                window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
            return(ret);
        }

        if (elem.addEventListener) {
            elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
        } else {
            elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
        }
    }



    function addClass(elem, cls) {
        var oldCls = elem.className;
        if (oldCls) {
            oldCls += " ";
        }
        elem.className = oldCls + cls;
    }

    function removeClass(elem, cls) {
        var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
        elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }


    function findItem(items, target) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] === target) {
                return(i);
            }
        }
        return(-1);
    }

    var keys = {up: 38, down: 40, left: 37, right: 39};
    var cards = document.getElementById("game-board").getElementsByClassName("card");
    addEvent(document, "keydown", function(e) {
        // get key press in cross browser way
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
        // number of items across
        var width = 4;
        var increment, index, newIndex, active;

        switch(code) {
            case keys.up:
                increment = -width;
                break;
            case keys.down:
                increment = width;
                break;
            case keys.left:
                increment = -1;
                break;
            case keys.right:
                increment = 1;
                break;
            default:
                increment = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (increment !== 0) {
            active = document.getElementById("game-board").getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
            index = findItem(cards, active);
            newIndex = index + increment;
            if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < cards.length) {
                removeClass(active, "active");
                addClass(cards[newIndex], "active");
            }
            // prevent default handling of up, down, left, right keys
            return false;
        }

    });
})();
```

```css
.active {
    background: #00ebe4;
    border:2px solid #93ff85;


    }

*{margin: 0; padding:0;}
body{
    font-family:arial;
    background: #5f5f5f;
}
#plan{
    margin:90px auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.84);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#game-board{
    width:380px;
    height:380px;
}




.card{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background: #3a89be 14px 7px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div align="center";
     style="color: #d8d8d8;
     margin-top: 50px" >

    <H1></H1>
    <h2>use Arrows to Navigate.</h2></div>
<div id="plan">
    <div id="game-board">

        <div class="card active" id="0"></div>
        <div class="card" id="1"></div>
        <div class="card" id="2"></div>
        <div class="card" id="3"></div>
        <div class="card" id="4"></div>
        <div class="card" id="5"></div>
        <div class="card" id="6"></div>
        <div class="card" id="7"></div>
        <div class="card" id="8"></div>
        <div class="card" id="9"></div>
        <div class="card" id="10"></div>
        <div class="card" id="11"></div>
        <div class="card" id="12"></div>
        <div class="card" id="13"></div>
        <div class="card" id="14"></div>
        <div class="card" id="15"></div>
    </div>

</div>
       <!-- <div id="restart"><button id="reset-button"></button>reset</div> -->

</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3aumn3y6/

Comment: Please don't post links to your code on 3rd party sites as it makes it more difficult to answer your question and those links can become broken over time, making your question useless. Just post your code right here, in a code snippet.

Comment: Now, your question is unclear. It sounds like you are asking us to decide what should happen as the user moves around. Please be more specific about what problem you are having, what you have tried and what you want to happen.

Comment: thanks, so there are multiple things happening at different boxes (lets keep it only one thing that is the box reduces to 2x2 size) but what i dont know is how to keep track of these actions on specific boxes, thanks

Comment: Your entire `attachHandler` function and your `attachEvent` code is only going to be useful if you plan to support IE 8, which really should not be on your radar unless you have a specific use case for it.

Comment: In fact, I don't see the value in just about all of your event related code. When attaching an anonymous function as an event handler, that function stays in memory as long as the DOM element it's attached to does. There is no way to save memory on those. Just use the DOM standard `.addEventListner()` and don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to your statement/clarification:

> "but what i dont know is how to keep track of these actions on
>   specific boxes, thanks"

Take a look at [event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) in javascript. I know you're using some above, but it looks like you may have copied from somewhere -- which is fine -- but it's in a way that makes them less then useful for this purpose. Event listeners are normally setup on specific elements on the page, using getElementById. Example:

HTML

`<button id='button1'>Click Me!</button>`

JS

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener("click", myFunction, true);

myFunction = function(){

     //here's where you change the color, or size, or make a popup window, etc.

};
```

Clicking on that particular button (which can also be any other HTML element) will execute the function.